# how can I change the default position of Text Editor (Gedit)?

Tags: gedit, text-editor

Using Ubuntu 21.04, GNOME 3.38.5
I am new to Linux.
I have grown accustomed to windows opening in their last-used location. I prefer my text editor (which I use a lot) on the right-hand side of my screen. (I prefer working with multiple windows.)
Text Editor (Gedit 3.38.1) opens on the left. Can I change this default location?
[The "key combination of ctrl+alt+[NumpadNumber] which positions the window" may have worked in earlier versions but doesn't now.]
I've browsed the Ubuntu software but the descriptions are quite opaque to a newbie like me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the default position question, but at least if you're running X as your windowing system you can use `xdotool` to reposition your windows. For example, you can add a custom keyboard shortcut to run `xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0` to move the active window top/left. If you use large numbers you push the window to the right/bottom.

Comment: While i was thrashing around looking for a way to shift the window to the right (or open in the last place where it was closed) I managed to get it set to open in the centre of the screen. This is much more useful for me, but I can't remember (or rediscover) how I did it... :-/
@bernt-ribbum

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to Language Tool. It remembers where I left it, and has automated spell (and grammar) checking. Slow to load (not sure why) but I've put it in startup applications.

Comment: I'm now using FeatherPad as my scratch pad.
It remembers where I ft it and has a spell-checker (though not on the fly). Much quicker to load than LangTool.